# Do not open Developer Tools when browser opens

Tags: node.js, chromium, playwright

When I run my tests, the Developer Tools panel is automatically open. Can I close it using Playwright? I don't need to see it.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this, https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#pwdebug

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `chromium.launch` you can disable DevTools from showing with the following config.

```js
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        devtools: false
    });
```

More information in the Playwright documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-option-devtools